# Date return in string order

Tags: javascript, html

my 4th assignment

Write a javascript function that returns the date. The date should be returned as a string in the order (DD-MM-YYYY) and in the following formats:
01-12-2016
01/12/2017
Tip: Make over an input argument that is chosen for the dash (-) or slash (/) as a separator stabbing.

I got this

```
<script>
function formattedDate(date) {
var vandaag = new Date(date || Date.now()),
    month = '' + (vandaag.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + vandaag.getDate(),
    year = vandaag.getFullYear();
if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
return [day, month, year].join('-');}
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (-) :  ' + formattedDate()); 

function formattedDat(date) {
var vandaa = new Date(date || Date.now()), 
    mont = '' + (vandaa.getMonth() + 1),
    da = '' + vandaa.getDate(),
    yea = vandaa.getFullYear();
if (mont.length < 2) mont = '0' + mont;
if (da.length < 2) da = '0' + da;
return [da, mont, yea].join('/');}
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (/):  ' + formattedDat());
</script
```

but i dont want it to write two times, and i need buttons for each order (-) and (/)

Comment: Why don't you pass the separator as a parameter to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one method and accept the separator as a parameter!

Fijne dag nog vandaag en succes ;)

```js
function formattedDate(seperator) {
  var vandaag = new Date(),
      month = '' + (vandaag.getMonth() + 1),
      day = '' + vandaag.getDate(),
      year = vandaag.getFullYear();
  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
  return [day, month, year].join(seperator);
}
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (-) :  ' + formattedDate('-')); 
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (/):  ' + formattedDate('/'));
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (+):  ' + formattedDate('+'));
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (=):  ' + formattedDate('='));
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (----):  ' + formattedDate('----'));
document.write('<br> Vandaag met (POKEMON):  ' + formattedDate('POKEMON'));
```